# Widrow-Hoff: Please Explain this Step

Tags: calculus

$$\Large \frac{\partial e^2(k)}{\partial w_{1,j}}=2e(k)\frac{\partial e(k)}{\partial w_{1,j}}$$

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPqKG.png))

Please explain this step above with error gradient.

Comment: This is called the *chain rule*. Look it up.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in the comments.